# C++ Operator Precedence?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I am trying to create a stack and queue linked list converting infix to postfix. Anyways, my question is, is there a function that returns the operator precedence?

I am basically trying to compare `'+'` and `'*'`, and have the function return TRUE, say if `'*' > '+'`, something along those lines. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. There's not such a thing. But it's easy to make

Comment: This would be a fun code-golf question.

Comment: How would you go on about making it, sehe? I have a couple of ideas, but none seem very efficient. The best one I came up with was making cases and assigning variables to each ASCII code.

Comment: @Maty: The most efficient is probably one mapping function, called twice, and a simple numeric comparison.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide an example? From what I understand, map each operator into a numeric value and then compare it, which was what I was going to do with the switch and cases, but I feel like this mapping isn't the same thing.

Comment: I highly recommend searching StackOverflow for "c++ calculator precedence".  There are sooooo many examples of the calculator program on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up, maybe make the code cleaner. But I found a way.

Comment: You could try to use some template magic to find out the precedence between two operators, and you can use a preprocessor macro to link the operators to their respective strings. I'm not into the details, but I'm positive that its possible.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the contribution, thought I'd post this if someone else ever needs same help. Might not be the most efficient code, but it works! That's all I need.

```
int precedenceMenu(float temp){

    switch((int)temp)
    {
    case '+':
        temp = '2';
    case '-':
        temp = '2';
    case '*':
        temp = '3';
    case '/':
        temp = '3';
    case '^':
        temp = '4';
    }
    return temp;
}

bool precedenceCheck(float inStack, float data){

    bool precedence;
    char stackChar, dataChar;

    if( precedenceMenu(inStack) >= precedenceMenu(data) )
        precedence = true;

    else
        precedence = false;

    return precedence;      //Returns TRUE if data >= inStack (therefor switch)
}
```

Comment: You need to add `break` after the assignment statements in the `cases` so that they don't fall into the next case.  Your post presently will assign 4 to `temp` for '+'.

Comment: If the variable temp falls into the '+' case, then I set it to be '2', it can't fall under any of the next cases.

Comment: Try again.  Use a debugger to single step the code or pass the '+' to your function and see what the result is.  Search StackOveflow for "c++ case break fall through"

Comment: Ah, you're right! Thank you very much. I was running the entire code on a simple function and it worked, I guess it was just luck.

Comment: Why are you using `float` as the type for the variable that holds the operator?!?

Comment: That's a very long-winded way of writing `return precedenceMenu(inStack) >= precedenceMenu(data);` Are you being paid per line of code?